# How to open another URL after executing base URL by using Selenium RC with Java

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-rc

I have following methods of my class `Test`: (Selenium RC, JUnit, Java, Eclipse)

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox","https://www.google.com/");
    selenium.start();
   }
@Test
public void testGoogle() throws Exception {
     selenium.open("https://www.google.com");
......
........
     }
```

After execution of Google site, I want to switch yahoo site from Google. I have written the following code of snippet:

```
@Test
public void testYahoo() throws Exception {
     selenium.open("http://www.yahoo.com/"); //error in this line
........
........
     }
```

I found the following errors:

> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
>       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:100)
>       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:94)
>       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.open(DefaultSelenium.java:343)
>       **at abc.Test.testYahoo(Test.java:47)**
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

How can I open another site rather than Base URL? Please help me

Ripon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to close previous selenium session or reuse `selenium` instance:

```
private static Selenium selenium;

@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox","https://www.google.com/");
    selenium.start();
}

@Test
public void testGoogle() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("https://www.google.com");
}

@Test
public void testYahoo() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("https://www.yahoo.com");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try *chrome instead of *firefox